# Activity Indicator doesn't work when MKMapView "Show User Location" box is checked

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot make an activity indicator work on top of a mapView when I select the "User Location" box for the MKMapView. I am calling the activity indicator while downloading CLLocations from iCloud.

The activity indicator's "Behavior Animating" box is checked and so is the "Hides When Stopped" box.
If I leave the mapView's User Location box unchecked, the activity indicator code works just fine.  But if I also check the mapView's "User Location" box, the activity indicator no longer appears.  I stop the activity indicator once all the CLLocation views (map pins) are added to the mapView.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
        ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
```

How can I make both the User Location and the activity indicator appear?

Comment: Put `ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()` in a more proper place. i.e.  in the completion handler of your download task.

Answer (score 0):

The user's location is an annotation added by the map view itself.

This causes your activity view to stop immediately, even though you haven't yet added your own annotations.

You should stop the activity indicator when you finish retrieving the data and add the annotations, not as a side effect of annotations being added.

Comment: Thanks.  Works like a charm now.